# Flutter - Align Items inside a Row - Multiple tiles

Tags: flutter, list, alignment, row

I have the following List.
I would like the scale Icons (on the right) to be aligned.
The top should be in the same spot as the one underneath.

[image]

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding:
          const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 0.0, top: 8.0, bottom: 8.0),
      child: Slidable(
        endActionPane: ActionPane(motion: StretchMotion(), children: [
          //delete option
          SlidableAction(
            onPressed: deleteTapped,
            backgroundColor: Colors.red.shade400,
            icon: Icons.delete,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          )
        ]),
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Color(0xFFD9F0FF),
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
            children: [
              const Icon(
                Icons.date_range_outlined,
                color: Color(0xFF006B8F),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 8),
              Text(date,
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Color(0xFF006B8F))),
              const Spacer(),
              const Text(
                "|",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 18,
                    color: Color(0xFF006B8F),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              const Icon(
                Icons.monitor_weight_outlined,
                color: Color(0xFF006B8F),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 8),
              Text(weight + " kg",
                  style: const TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Color(0xFF006B8F))),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried several things, like putting the Icon and the text in a container but with no luck.

Any help appreciate it!

Comment: Biobrolly you want to display `|` vertical line is stright? for all list

Comment: Yes but also the scale icon on the right and the text of the kilos

Answer (score 1):

While you are already using `Spacer` on both Size, you can use

`textAlign: TextAlign.center,`

```dart
 const Text(
  "|",
  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
  style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 18,
      color: Color(0xFF006B8F),
      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
),
```

Without spacer, it can be

```dart
Expanded(
  child: const Text(
    "|",
    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 18,
        color: Color(0xFF006B8F),
        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  ),
),
```

Comment: The problem is that because some text on the right has more chars than other all the things on the left get shifted. So it is not the problem of the midl |

Comment: did you try with Expanded and textAlign center

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
      Column(
              children: [
                IntrinsicHeight(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          //left part
                        ],
                      ),
                      VerticalDivider(),
                      Row(
                        
                        children: [
                          //right part
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                ....
                
              ],
            )
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it does not solve the problem. I get the same result.